# Display Text Resolution Blurred

Tags: windows-8, display

I have not changed anything on my computer related to screen or text resolution. But one day I found every browser showing larger blurred texts. See the images.

[image]

I have tried to change the size of text items from `Resolution->Make text larger or smaller` but already defined ones are very small or very large. I also tried custom defined the the best I could do is on the picture - sizes might be ok but they are blurred once I scroll browser window (sometimes even without scrolling). (You see on the picture even the first one is blurred somewhat...)

Any idea what can the reason or solution be?

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Is the browser at the default zoom level?

Comment: Any browser (as I wrote above). Yes they are not zoomed or something...

Comment: The screen looks like I zoomed the browser windows by touching (without changing browser ZOOM).
P.S. I have touch screen.

Comment: What are your Windows' video resolution and DPI set to?

Comment: 1920x1080 and "Scale to the percentage of the normal size": 115% (I have tried all)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting some ClearType settings - it might do the trick. Go to [this webpage](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-text-easier-read-cleartype#1TC=windows-7) for detailed directions on how to do this. Good luck!

Comment: mm... I have tried a few times.

Comment: I see. It might be a browser issue. Are you using Chrome? Try this if you are: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fonts-appear-blurred-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry editing fixed the font thickness issue for me completely, 
we can tune the font thicknes/darkness by calibrating  FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA  value to 
between 150 and 190 hexadecimal( 336 to 400 decimal )

- START  ->  RUN  ->  REGEDIT
- search for  FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA   by  keying  "Ctrl F"
     ( will automatically take us to  CurrentUser\ControlPanel\Desktop  path)
- right-click mouse on  FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA on the rightside, Modify... enter any 
    thing between 150 and 190 hexadecimal.
      (the Lower the value, the thicker the fonts.)
- close the REGEDIT tool
- LOGOFF and then LOGON

Now all the fonts are very thick & very dark in Chrome Browser.

But we must make sure that ClearType smoothing is enabled in Windows
( controlPanel  ->  personalization  ->  appearance
          ->   Effects  ->  ClearType smooth check (ticked box) )

```
                     OR  alternately in RegEdit ...
```

FONTSMOOTHING=2      FONTSMOOTHINGTYPE=2
  FONTSMOOTHINGORIENTATION=1  for LCD-screen,  0 for CRT-screen